# Python: loop over a matrix to check for all values in a vector

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, vector

I have this vector: `possibleGrades=np.array([-3,0,2,4,7,10,12])`

And I want the computer to tell me where in this matrix there are values which are not from the vector:

```
    [[ 7.   7.   4. ]
 [12.  10.  10. ]
 [-3.   7.   2. ]
 [10.   8.  12. ]
 [ nan  7.   nan]
 [ 7.   7.  10. ]
 [ 4.5  nan  2. ]
 [ 2.  12.   4. ]]
```

My idea:

```
for i in range(matrixGr):
    if (-3) in matrixGr:
        pass
    elif 0 in matrixGr:
        pass
    elif 2 in matrixGr:
        pass
    elif 4 in matrixGr:
        pass
    elif 7 in matrixGr:
        pass
    elif 10 in matrixGr:
        pass
    elif 12 in matrixGr:
        pass
    else:
        print("The data set contains incorrect grades at {location?}!")
```

But this is not possible and how to do it is beyond what my mental capacity can conduct.

What is a smart and possible way?

It would be very nice if it was possible to say like "row X contains invalid grade 8 (e.g.)", so something with string " row {:s} has the invalid grade {:s}" and .format("something smart")

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
import numpy as np

possibleGrades = np.array([-3, 0, 2, 4, 7, 10, 12])

matrixGr = np.array([[7, 7, 4],
                   [12, 10, 10],
                   [-3, 7, 2],
                   [10, 8, 12],
                   [np.nan, 7, np.nan],
                   [7, 7, 10],
                   [4.5, np.nan, 2],
                   [2, 12, 4]])

locations = [(i, j) for i in range(matrixGr.shape[0]) for j in range(matrixGr.shape[1]) if matrixGr[i, j] not in possibleGrades]
```

```
locations:
[(3, 1), (4, 0), (4, 2), (6, 0), (6, 1)]
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

```
possibleGrades = np.array([-3,0,2,4,7,10,12])
matrix = np.array([
    [ 7. ,  7.,   4. ],
    [12.,  10.  ,10. ],
    [-3.,   7.  , 2. ],
    [10.,   8.  ,12. ],
    [ np.nan,  7.  , np.nan],
    [ 7. ,  7.  ,10. ],
    [ 4.5,  np.nan , 2. ],
    [ 2. , 12.,   4. ]
])
line, col = np.where(np.isin(matrix, possibleGrades, invert=True))
print('locations:')
[print(f'Invalid value {matrix[line[i],col[i]]} at location ({line[i]},{col[i]})') for i in range(line.size)]
```

You should get the result:

```
locations:
Invalid value 8.0 at location (3,1)
Invalid value nan at location (4,0)
Invalid value nan at location (4,2)
Invalid value 4.5 at location (6,0)
Invalid value nan at location (6,1)
```

- [np.isin](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html): find elements in the vector but the option invert=True enable to invert the result.
- [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html): finds the lines and columns corresponding to True elements.

Comment: Thank you! It was very helpful! 

Now I have a follow-up question:

`
line, col = np.where(np.isin(matrixGrades, possibleGrades, invert=True))
print('Displaying incorrect or missing grades: \n')
[print(f'Incorrect or missing grade in row {line[i]} in column {col[i]}! Displaying the incorrect grade: {INSERT VALUE}.') for i in range(line.size)]`

How can I do this? So it displays the value from the row that is incorrect? I tried `matrix[i]`but does not work. I also wonder, can I edit somehow so it does not start with row 1 is 0, but actually row 1 and column 1 is 1 and not column 0?

Comment: I edited the answer. To start at value one you can add one to the line and col arrays so that (1,1) corresponds to the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple oneliner that returns the indices that are not in your list of "goodgrades" using list comprehension and the enumerate() function:

```
goodgrades = [-3,0,2,4,7,10,12]
testgrades = [10,-3,11]
badgrades = [ind for ind, i in enumerate(testgrades) if i not in goodgrades]
```

testgrades = [7,10,7] returns nothing, while [7,-1,7] returns [1].

To expand this to a list of grade lists, you can use this as a function:

```
def checkgrades(grades):
    return [ind for ind, i in enumerate(grades) if i not in goodgrades]
```

now, you can use it in a loop and print test results row by row:

```
for row in range(len(grades)):
    badgrades = checkgrades(grades[row])
    if badgrades != []:
        print('Bad grades found in row {} at indices {}'.format(row, badgrades))
```

Comment: Note: while this approach is a bit more verbose than Robustus answer, this works for lists that have different numbers of grades for each sublist of grades. Both approaches are valuable, depends on what you need!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner that returns a boolean matrix the same size as `matrixGr`, with True if the grade is in `possibleGrades` and False otherwise:

```
>>> np.any(np.stack([grade==matrixGr for grade in possibleGrades]),axis=0)
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```

If you want the opposite, just add `np.logical_not()` around it:

```
>>> np.logical_not(np.any(np.stack([e==mat for e in possibleGrades]),axis=0))
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False]])
```

In brief, what it does is that it builds a boolean matrix for each grade in `possibleGrades`, then aggregates all the result.